# How to speed up mySQL query when I only need the latest entry of each group?

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance

So I was working on a project about transportation system. There are buses reporting to the server. All buses insert new rows into a table called Events every 2 sec, so it is a large table.

Each bus has a unique busID. I want to get a table which contains all buses but only their latest report.

Here are things I tried:

- Firstly I think I could `ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 20` It turns out that it is sorting the entire table first then doing the LIMIT thing second... which actually make sense, how else could it sort?
- So I was googling and found out that its much faster to sort with the index. So i did `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20;` It gave me the latest 20 entries pretty fast.
- However I don't really need the latest 20 entries instead that I need the latest entry from all buses. So I was thinking about combining `GROUP BY bus` with `ORDER BY id` somehow but didn't really figure that out...
- Next I read about another post on this site about speeding things up when you only need the max value of a column in each group. So finally I came up with `SELECT driver,busID,route,timestamp,MAX(id) FROM Events GROUP BY bus` However it seems like using MAX(id) does not really help...
- And I think about first using `ORDER BY id LIMIT (some number)` to make a sub table, then find the newest entry of each bus within the sub table. But a problem is that, the tablet on the bus which is sending report might accidentally go offline thus unable to insert new rows. So I don't really know how large should I make the sub table so that it contains at least the latest entry of each bus...

So I am kinda running out of ideas... I am still a noob in mySQL, so maybe there are other better functions to use? Or maybe I am complexing things? I though it wouldn't be so hard to do at the begin ...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

---

I also read about this [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group?rq=1) which is brilliant! But it still takes forever in my case...

---

```
CREATE TABLE `Events` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `driver` varchar(200) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `bus` varchar(200) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `route` varchar(50) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `time` datetime default NULL,
  `clientTime` datetime default NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(30,20) default NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(30,20) default NULL,
  `accuracy` int(11) default NULL,
  `speed` decimal(30,20) default NULL,
  `heading` decimal(30,20) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=66528487 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

---

Thank you all for helping me！ But it is time to talk to professor! Maybe I am not supposed to do that hmm...

Comment: have you tried `MAX(timestamp) over (partition by busID order by index desc)`

Comment: Thanks for replying I'll try it :)

Comment: Use a Trigger and insert/update a second table that holds only one record per bus (busID Primary) like insert into new_table ...... ON DUPLICATE JEY UPDATE ......; so you have a very small table with all informations you want

Comment: But I don't really have control over the database.. I can only query it. I was thinking maybe we had a table with only the latest report too. But I didn't really find anything like that... ah maybe I missed it, I should look at other tables again I guess...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html Provides an alternative solution to left join. The speed of any sort heavily depends on the size of your table / preselected result records and that you have an index on the timestamp column

Comment: Thank you for whomever helped me with the format.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use indexes: id is a primary key and is already indexed, so sorting by id should be fast, but bus and time are not indexed. I would add a composite unique index like this:

```
alter table Events add unique index idx_bus_time (bus, time);
```

this should make the following query much faster:

```
select bus, max(time)
from Events
group by bus
```

then you can easily get the last info for each bus:

```
select e.*
from Events e INNER JOIN (
  select bus, max(time) max_time
  from Events
  group by bus) l on e.bus=l.bus AND e.time=l.max_time
```

another thing you can do to improve performances is to create a busses table:

```
create table busses (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  bus varchar(200)
)
```

and alter the original table, and use a `bus_id INT` instead of the `bus VARCHAR(200)`, and index the bus_id and the time column together.

Comment: Thanks! I will talk to my professor and see if we can get them indexed.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  5.6 will let you add the index without locking the table.  Otherwise, use pt-online-schema-change to add the index with virtually zero downtime.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather make it simple,

I would add one column in the table i.e. < latest_record >...

Now, for the particular < bus_id >'s latest record or Event, 
it would have value < 0 > in < latest_record > field.

once another entry/event for the same < bus_id > is arrived, 
before inserting that entry/event,
I would update previous_latest entry/event's < latest_record >'s value to '1'
and 
the newly arrived entry will have < latest_record >'s value to '0'

Now, you just have to make Index on < latest_record >
and you can find all unique bus_id's latest entry by 
filtering latest_record='0' in WHERE clause

Comment: Thanks! Too bad I don't have control over the database ...  It is apparently doable though because we have an old api which will just return what I want and it is fast. I don't know what query statement they were using though. I started to feel like maybe there are other useful tables... I will take another look on other tables too

Comment: can you give result of  SHOW CREATE TABLE < your_table > ?

Comment: Just added to the op.

Comment: It's not what I'd do.

Comment: @Strawberry, You might have reckoned - adding a column in very large table....  so this solution's possibly not recommended ! May be Adding multi-column index on (busid, timestamp) with tricky query would solve it...What's your solution ?

Comment: fthiella's pretty much nailed it

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be so simple if you could simply `INSERT` into a new table that contains one row per `bus` -- the current status of the bus.